# Projection Matrix Breaks My Rectangle

Tags: opengl, glsl, matrix, projection, projection-matrix

This is my vertex shader, shown below.

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 a_position;
in vec4 a_colour;

// FOV = 70, near plane = 0.1, far plane = 1000
const mat4 u_projection = mat4(
    1.428148, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.428148, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0001999, -0.20002,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0
);

//uniform mat4 u_projection;
//uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_transformation;

out vec4 v_colour;

void main() {

   gl_Position = u_projection * u_transformation * vec4(a_position, 1);
   v_colour = a_colour;
}
```

Whenever I take out `u_projection`, my square appears. When I add it back, the square is malformed.

The vertices of my square are as follows, aka the contents of `a_position`.

```
float[] vertices = {
    0, 0, 0.5f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
    0, 0.5f, 0.5f,
    0, 0, 0.5f,
    0f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
    0, 0.5f, 0.5f
};
```

The position of the square is `(0, 0, 0)`, the rotation is `(0, 0, 0)` and the scale is `1`. These are computed into `u_transformation` and uploaded. This works perfectly.

If I change the `-1.0001999` and the last `0` to `1` part to 1 then the square is not hidden.

```
void bindAttribute(int index, String name) {
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(program, index, name);
}
bindAttribute(0, "a_position");
bindAttribute(1, "a_colour");
```

Comment: what happens if you move the rectangle by + or -0.2 in x axis?

Comment: There's actually a bit more missing information. What aspect ratio did you use to calculate the projection matrix?

Comment: @wondra, http://imgur.com/a/BuOHw - first: x=0, second: x=0.2, third: x=-0.2, that's really strange! This is with the matrix applied.

Comment: @Nasser, the ratio is 500 / 800 pixels

Comment: The square is now malformed when the matrix is applied (as I wasn't doing it correctly before).

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that your transfomation matrix is broken. Try to remove `* u_transformation `. If it will not help, try to transpose projection matrix.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ah, I've transposed the projection matrix (http://pastebin.com/bpQiy8zL) and tested the transformation on its own and it appears to work perfectly. The projection on its own hides it due to the Z coord (but the square shows enlarged when I set the Z coord to -1 and keep XY). The transformation on its own does its thing well. Strangely, transformation * projection = blank but the other way round, we get this: http://imgur.com/BoSaUDd

Comment: @Lolums, fix your vertices first!!!

Comment: There's something fishy going on. With the information you've given, you shouldn't have a rectangle appear. Can you show your `glVertexAttribPointer` calls?

Comment: @Nasser, sure, I'll add the calls in

Comment: @Lolumns, swap the two values in the matrix and move the square to Z=-0.5. He was asking about that because of your kinda-confusing description of a rectangle (that's actually a triangle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's something fishy about your vertices. If we write them out properly:

```
float[] vertices = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, // (1)
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, // (2)
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, // (3)
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, // (1)
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, // (3)
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f  // (3) 
};
```

You have only 3 distinct vertices, so if you are seeing a rectangle, then you need to call you GPU manufacturer! (or check your `glVertexAttribPointer` calls)

Your projection matrix doesn't look correct... I believe the reason your triangle (it's not a rectangle) is disappearing is that you are specifying your projection matrix in row-major order. The way you represented your matrix:

```
const mat4 u_projection = mat4(
    1.428148, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.428148, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0001999, -0.20002,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0
);
```

Actually produces the following transformation matrix:

```
[1.428148, 0.0     , 0.0       ,  0.0 ]
[0.0     , 1.428148, 0.0       ,  0.0 ]
[0.0     , 0.0     , -1.0001999, -1.0 ]
[0.0     , 0.0     , -0.20002  ,  0.0 ]
```

This also implies that you are using an aspect ratio of 1.0, whereas you state in the comments that you have a 500x800 aspect ratio, but let's stick to this matrix for now. What you should have is:

```
const mat4 u_projection = mat4(
    1.428148, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.428148, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0001999, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -0.20002, 0.0
);
```

Notice that the `-1.0` and the `-0.20002` are swapped.

Now, let's multiply the transformation matrix by the coordinates of your triangle (again there are only 3), the clip-space coordinates we get are:

vertex (1): [`0.0, 0.0, -0.70012, -0.5`]

vertex (2): [`0.714074, 0.714074, -0.70012, -0.5`]

vertex (3): [`0.0, 0.714074, -0.70012, -0.5`]

Ah! We have a negative w value, and a more negative z value (-0.5 and -0.70012, respectively). This is because you placed your z-values at 0.5, when by OpenGL convention, in view space, the negative z axis points away from the viewer, so you should change those to -0.5, so that the triangle actually lies between your near and far clip planes.

So, let's say we do that, our unique vertices become:

```
float[] vertices = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f, // (1)
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, // (2)
    0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, // (3)
};
```

Now, your clip space coordinates become:

vertex (1): [`0.0, 0.0, -0.3008, 0.5`]

vertex (2): [`0.714074, 0.714074, -0.3008, 0.5`]

vertex (3): [`0.0, 0.714074, -0.3008, 0.5`]

Now, your triangle should be partially in your window; i.e., because vertices 2 and 3 are actually outside of clip space. Remember that, if you want your triangle to (at least partially) appear, then at least one if its coordinates has to have all x, y and z values between -w and +w. There are several things you can do to fix this, such as increasing your fov angle. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I think his geometry was degenerate, so he looked for problems. Since his proj is wrong, someone suggested Transpose() which he tried and then hardcoded into the shader as a Row-Column-Row-Major matrix, LOL. So, by Transposing() it back to Row-Column-Row-Column-Major it "appears to work perfectly". I can't imagine how many different things he's tried.

Comment: @Jon, a lot of things! I've learnt what transposing is though. The hard coding was temporary and just to ask the question.

Comment: @Nasser, thanks a bunch. The killer actually was my `glVertexAttribPointer` calls. The `4` should have been a `3` for attribute size. After 3 hours, I will _never_ forget that.

Comment: @Lolums, wow I was certain (again) it was going to be the first two really easy things and that glVertexAttribPointer wasn't relevant. Since I use DirectX, can you (or anyone) confirm if this is analogous to a DX InputLayout? Was the incorrect setting loading Point2's X into Point1's W?

Comment: @Jon, well, I have never used DirectX so I've no idea. Basically, I specified that each attribute is 4 floats long when it's actually 3 floats (X, Y and Z for position and R, G and B for colour).

Comment: @Lolums OpenGL is quite an awkward API, with subpar tools for debugging. I've found that the best way to learn is by making mistakes like this one